# How to create a property binding in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I am looking for a generic solution to specify relationships between properties so that **if a dependency of a property changes, the value of the property is automatically updated**.

I am aware that this is not an odd idea and e.g. there is a [solution in Qt](https://www.qt.io/blog/all-about-property-bindings-in-qt-6.2), but I didn't find a similar one in the .NET Framework.

I want to achieve something like this:

```csharp
public class Rectangle
{
    public IProperty<int> Height;
    public IProperty<int> Width;
    public IProperty<int> Area;
    
    public Rectangle(int height, int width)
    {
        Height = new Property<int>(height);
        Width = new Property<int>(width);
        Area = new Property<int>(() => Height.Value * Width.Value);
    }
}
```

Which in use could be like this:

```csharp
var rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20); // rectangle.Area.Value == 200
rectangle.Width.Value = 5;             // rectangle.Area.Value == 50
```

The `IProperty` interface might look something like this:

```csharp
public interface IProperty<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }

    event EventHandler ValueChanged;
}
```

My idea was that when the `Area` property is initialized, it would have to subscribe to (and somehow unsubscribe from) the `ValueChanged` event of all `IProperty` objects in the lambda expression. Later, if an `IProperty` object raises a `ValueChanged` event, the `Area` property would evaluate the lambda expression.

- Is all this possible in the .NET Framework? If so, how can this be achieved?
- What if the lambda expression includes a collection of `IProperty` objects?

Comment: https://reactiveui.net

Comment: The way that the NET constituent classes do this is to make `Area` a method which does the calculation on demand.  It is generally a bad idea to cache or store anything which is easily calculated.  A `Person.Age` vs a `BirthDay` property is an example

Comment: Would `public IProperty<int> Area => Height.Value * Width.Value` suffice?